# Bad mySQL query

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which I would expect to return only records matching the label_name "Ultra Music", however it returns any label_name:

```
SELECT  `chart_rating` . * , SUM( chart_rating.rating_score ) AS total_score, release.release_label
FROM  `chart_rating` 
INNER JOIN  `release` ON  `chart_rating`.`rating_release_id` =  `release`.`id` 
WHERE MATCH (
release.release_label
)
AGAINST (
"Ultra Music"
IN BOOLEAN MODE
)
GROUP BY  `rating_release_id` 
ORDER BY  `total_score` DESC
```

I have an almost identical query for release_artist which works perfectly.

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: You're probably running afoul of MySQL's `GROUP BY` lenience, a very common problem - it would be an error in most other RDBMS to include only one one column in `GROUP BY` when the `SELECT` has many - MySQL permits it, but the results are often indeterminate. Post a sample of rows from the table together with a sample of what you expect your query to return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default (when neither + nor - is specified) the word is optional, but the rows that contain it are rated higher. This mimics the behavior of MATCH() ... AGAINST() without the IN BOOLEAN MODE modifier.

[MySQL Ref - Bool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: nice find would be good though if you could add also an example of how he should modify the sql accordingly.

Comment: Thank you bluepinto, never knew this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing `space` using `REPLACE`,

Then add `+UltraMusic`

```
 SELECT  `chart_rating` . * , SUM( chart_rating.rating_score ) AS total_score, release.release_label
    FROM  `chart_rating` 
    INNER JOIN  `release` ON  `chart_rating`.`rating_release_id` =  `release`.`id` 
    WHERE MATCH (
    REPLACE(release.release_label,' ','')
    )
    AGAINST (
    "+UltraMusic"
    IN BOOLEAN MODE
    )
    GROUP BY  `rating_release_id` 
    ORDER BY  `total_score` DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use simple comparison.

```
SELECT  `chart_rating` . * , SUM( chart_rating.rating_score ) AS total_score, release.release_label
FROM  `chart_rating` 
INNER JOIN  `release` ON  `chart_rating`.`rating_release_id` =  `release`.`id` 
WHERE release.release_label = "Ultra Music"
GROUP BY  `rating_release_id` 
ORDER BY  `total_score` DESC
```

In case you really need full text search where clause may look like this: `MATCH (release.release_label) AGAINST ("+Ultra +Music" IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: There may only be partial of the name used, eg. "Ultra" rather than "Ultra Music"